# С чем вообще взаимодействует программист при работе с TCP/IP

Tags: dart, tcp, ос

Пытаюсь освоить теорию по tcp/ip, конкретно TCP. Но, блин, столько воды и теоретической чепухи. Неделю смотрю и читаю, но ответов конкретных найти не могу.
Нужно чтобы более опытные люди расстолковали несколько вопросов, в понимании которых я не уверен.
Правильно ли я их понимаю:

1. Для отправки сообщения по протоколу tcp мне нужно создать сокет, указать протокол tcp, соеденить с сокетом получателя и когда я отправляю сообщение методом send, я просто вкладываю туда сообщение составленное по правилам того протокола, который мне необходим. Так ли это? (Интересует суть вопроса, не готовые библиотеки)
2. Капался в исходниках класса socket в dart. Реализации методов socket api таких как bind, connect и тп нет, есть обьявления методов в абстрактном классе и они обозначены как external. То есть их нет в библиотеке. Значит-ли, что реализация этих методов написана на с++ например, и вообще является частью api операционной системы?
   Значит-ли это что мне туда лезть не надо а все что язык дает мне, это создать сокет соединение и послать в него сообщение, а низкоуровневые дела делает компилятор?
   И значит-ли это что все языки высокого уровня дают возможность, через стандартные библиотеки взаимодействовать с api операционной системы, но сама реализация этого взаимодействия отсутствует в коде самого языка и спрятана в компиляторах и интерпритаторах?
3. Если все описанное выше, я понял правильно, значит-ли это, что если я хочу применять разные протоколы прикладного уровня как программист, мне нафиг не нужно знать ничего, кроме умения работать с сокетами и знаний как скомпоновать сообщение по тому или иному протоколу?

Comment: 1. Да; 2. Это реализовано в ядре ОС, в библиотеках только обёртки над системными вызовами; 3. Да

Comment: Я бы дополнил пункт  3, ДА,  *до определенного уровня  ваших программ это так*.  Надеюсь, концепции (и массу неочевидных деталей), описанных в man 7 (address_families arp ddp epoll icmp ip ipv6 net* packet rtnetlink sock_diag socket tcp udp udplite unix vsock wireless x25) прочли?

Comment: @avp так ли оно надо обычному программисту обычного прикладного ПО? Ну, наверно стоит понимать разницу между tcp и udp и примерно знать как выглядит ipv6-адрес, а вот остальное не припомню чтобы пригождалось как минимум в моей личной практике

Comment: @andreymal, а setsockopt вы никогда не использовали? Вообще, чтобы написаь грамотную сетевую программу надо бы представлять, как работает сетка в целом, со всеми роутингами и DNS-ами

Comment: @avp кажется, единственный раз, когда я его использовал — это чтобы навесить SO_REUSEADDR для обхода проблем с занятым сокетом, но потом я научился закрывать сокеты нормально и это стало не нужно) Не знаю, может, setsockopt используется где-то во внутренностях библиотек, но до меня как конечного программиста это не доходит